# Read data from PyIUknown type variable

Tags: python, vb.net, com, pywin32, win32com

I'm using `win32com.client` to read data from custom COM Object developed in VB.Net.

With the following code I'm able to read a string result

```
>>> import win32com.client
>>> cstApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("CustomLib.CSTApp")
>>> string = cstApp.GiveMeTestString()
>>> print(type(string))
<class 'str'>
>>> print("Test String: {0}".format(string))
Test String: Well done! I come from COM Object
```

I've now a method that give as result a VB.Net Dictionary type, but when I try to read it from my python script I get a PyIUknown type and I'm not able to read its values

```
>>> username = 'artur'
>>> resultset = cstApp.OpenTaskforUser(username)
>>> print(type(resultset))
<class 'PyIUnknown'>
>>> print(resultset)
<PyIUnknown at 0x0000003C47ABAC30 with obj at 0x0000003C47EAFF18>
```

How can I read it's data?

Otherwise, which type I need to use in VB.Net to be able to read a Python list containing dictionaries from `win32com`?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

After a week of working I've better understood how works `win32com` and Python support of COM interface, so I wanna share the workaround I've used to avoid the situation for which I posted this question.

**1. First of all **PyIUnknown** is not an error**. IUnknown Interface is the root Interface from which derive all other Interface. IUnknown (and so PyIUnknown) could be used through `QueryInterface` method. [[1]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680509(v=vs.85).aspx)

**2. On the other hand , not all Python Types are mapped in a COM Interface**. So IDictionary is one of them. This is why I get the PyIUnknown result. [[2]](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/html/com/win32com/HTML/PythonCOM.html)

**3. To use easly a COM Interface in Python is useful to generate a static proxy class** that maps all the interfaces available in the library. There are different ways to do this activity. In the early steps I've used `makepy` method . Then I've used `EnsureDispatch` one. [[3]](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/generate-a-static-com-proxy.html)

The final workaround, to avoid the problems at point 1. and 2., was to ask to custom API COM developer to change the returned type from a IDictionary to JSON string.

In this way I get a easily to use Python dictionary.

```
>>> import win32com.client
>>> import json
>>> cstApp = win32com.client..gencache.EnsureDispatch("CustomLib.CSTApp")
>>> resultset_json = cstApp.OpenTaskforUser('artur')
>>> type(resultset_json)
<class 'str'>
>>> resultset = json.loads(resultset_json)
>>> type(resultset)
<class 'dict'>
```

I hope this answer could help other people.